# Place Bootstrap Modal at beginning of specified DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use a Bootstrap Modal, to show bigger version of thumbnails in a photo gallery.

The default behavior of Bootstrap is to place the bootstrap at the top of the viewport, which usually is quite alright. But in this case, people are using the gallery in an `iframe`. Because of this, I want the modal dialog appears in the same height as the top of the gallery div.

I've tried positioning the modal dialog with CSS (top: 123px) but since the content above the gallery is constantly changing, this won't work. I would love to position the modal relative to the gallery with all the images.

EDIT: The link to the code is: http://bit.ly/1JCpZ9a

Comment: have you tried using the `show` event callback to reposition modal?

Comment: if you paste some code we can faster help you.

Comment: My apologies @Guarana, added URL to code now.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure what you are referring to. I tried searching through Bootstrap documentation without finding anything that seemed right to use.

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Answer (score 0):

Just do as you mentioned! Position it relative :-)

```
    #myModal {
        top:0;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Just make sure that the modal markup immediately follows the gallery. The content after the gallery is going to jump down when the dialog appears - but I'm hoping that you don't have content (you mentioned it was an iframe)

Otherwise you'll need to have a wrapper div wrapping this extra content and position the modal absolutely w.r.t that wrapper div.

Comment: It didn't work I'm afraid. After I did those exact changes, the modal started appearing in the top of the viewport (as the default behavior).

The code can be found on this page; http://bit.ly/1JCpZ9a

Comment: That page doesn't seem to be it. The modals don't follow the gallery (it's actually after the parent of the gallery) and they don't have the CSS set. Also with this gallery layout you would definitely need that wrapper div.